# Seeing lots of exception in collectionSelfLink

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm seeing a lot of exceptions in the collectionSelfLink when making DocumentDb call -- see image below.

I'm able to connect to DocumentDb and read data but these exceptions concern me -- especially in something that's pretty straight forward like a collectionSelfLink.

Any idea what may be causing them and how to fix them?
[image]

Here's the function that's using the selfLink

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> ReadQuery<T>(string dbName, string collectionId, SqlQuerySpec query)
{
   // Prepare collection self link
   // IMPORTANT: This is where I'm seeing those exceptions when I inspect the collectionLink. Otherwise, I'm NOT getting any errors.
   var collectionLink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(dbName, collectionId);

   var result = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(collectionLink, query, null);
   _client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(collectionLink);
   return await result.QueryAsync();
}
```

And here's the QueryAsync() extension method

```
public async static Task<IEnumerable<T>> QueryAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
{
   var docQuery = query.AsDocumentQuery();
   var batches = new List<IEnumerable<T>>();

   do
   {
      var batch = await docQuery.ExecuteNextAsync<T>();
      batches.Add(batch);
   }

   while (docQuery.HasMoreResults);
   var docs = batches.SelectMany(b => b);

   return docs;
}
```

Comment: What actual call did you make? You might want to edit your question to show the code that caused these errors.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Just added the function that uses the collectionLink. It's the first line that creates the collectionLink and it's only using two simple string parameters it receives to create the collectionLink i.e. dbName and collectionId. I don't know why I'd see those exceptions.

Comment: So SelfLink is an internal property that is set by DocumentDB. It cannot be set by the user and will only be populated on resources that have been returned from a call to the server.

Answer (score 0):

So SelfLink is an internal property that is set by DocumentDB. It cannot be set by the user and will only be populated on resources that have been returned from a call to the server.

The UriFactory code that you are using is construction a link that can be used to execute operations, but it is not a SelfLink.

If you are looking at a SelfLink property on a newly initialized DocumentCollection() object the SelfLink will be null as it has not been persisted on the server yet. This would explain all those errors in debug watch.